# UINavigationController alternatives

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller

I'm developing an app that resembles the structure of a 'Choose your own adventure' book, with lots of multimedia content (photos and videos mainly). Each 'page' is a `ViewController` in which the user has to complete a puzzle or another task in order to go to the next one.

I'm creating a `UINavigationController` and I'm pushing every new `ViewController` on top of the stack. But I'm worried about having memory issues since there is some heavy multimedia content and I'm not popping any `ViewController`, 90% of the time the user can't go back to the previous `ViewController`, just forward to a new one.

I'd like an alternative in which every time I jump to a new `ViewController` the old one gets released from memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to go back then you should get rid of your old `UIViewController` instances. You can do so after a new instance of `UIViewController` has been pushed to the UINavigationController stack.

One option is to just replace the `navigationController.viewControllers` array in the `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your view controllers being pushed to the `navigationController`. Means, you are going to need it in every `UIViewController` instance.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[viewController];
}
```

Second option is useful if you are using a main container controller that handles the pushing of your new `UIViewController` instances. Just implement `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocol and implement `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` method as shown below.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[viewController];
}
```

It should reset your `navigationController`s controller stack after a new instance has been pushed.

Obviously you can modify this logic to not remove the ones you want to go back to at some point.

Comment: It looks promising. I haven't got the time now to test it, but I'll do it tomorrow and and come back to accept the answer if any of the options do the trick.

Comment: I've tried your first option, adding `self.navigationController.viewcontrollers = @[self]` to every `ViewController` and when I log the array it shows only the current one, as expected, but the memory usage remains the same.

Look at memory usage with your solution: [HERE](http://postimg.org/image/ftn5vpnhn/) and without it [HERE](http://postimg.org/image/hqlj76xh5/)

Comment: @guardabrazo - your memory count has a difference of 6mb. One is 278 and other is 272. This is going to remove them from `UINavigationController` for sure but they will stick around if they are retained some place else in your app.

Comment: I've created a new question with an example project to download. Check it out [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409484/uiviewcontroller-not-being-released-from-memory-when-popped)

Answer (score 0):

The UINavigationController class allows you read and write the array of view controllers it uses to implement its stack however you like.  You're not restricted to just pushing and popping the view controllers.

In your case, each time a user moves to the next *page* of the app you should evaluate whether or not you need to keep the last one around.  If you do, you can just push it into the stack, however, if you don't, you should pull it out of the array and then use the setViewControllers:animated: method to set the view controller stack appropriately.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use Page View controller to move back and forth

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html

Comment: Does `UIPageViewController` release every `UIViewController` when it's not being shown?

Comment: at the time of allocating an instance you can pass autorelease if your code is Non-ARC , while in the case of ARC , it will release those when its not being shown