# Weak instance of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `UINavigationController` in which I push several `UIViewControllers`. 
I want that every time a new `UIViewController` is pushed, the older ones get released from memory.

For that, in every `UIViewController` I'm putting this piece of code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear{

    self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[self];
}
```

This way the `viewControllers` array gets reduced only to the one being displayed. But since I'm using ARC, every `UIViewController` is a strong reference and it's not being released from memory.

I've tried creating a weak instance of every `UIViewcontroller` when pushing them using this code:

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];

    __weak SecondViewController *weakSecondVC = secondVC;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:weakSecondVC animated:NO];
}
```

But this way I'm creating two instances: the weak one that is being pushed and the strong one that stays in memory.

I have also tried creating just the weak reference and pushing it:

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender{

    __weak SecondViewController *weakSecondVC;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:weakSecondVC animated:NO];
}
```

But then I get the following:
`Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x127606210>.`

Is there any way to achive this?

EDIT:
As suggested in the answer I've tried doing the following:

```
-(void)goToSecond:(id)sender{

   SecondViewController *pistasVC = [[EYSPistasViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController setViewControllers: @[secondVC]];
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
```

The `UINavigationController` stack of `UIViewController` it's reduced to the one I'm setting, but the memory still keeps adding up.

Here you can see a comparison of both methods:
[image]

Comment: Do you know `UINavigationController` provides a `popViewControllerAnimated:` method as well? It allows you to remove topmost controller. If you pass `NO` it will not perform the animation.

Comment: If you don't want to keep them why are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: @Amar I know about `popViewControllerAnimated:` but It just works with a `UIViewController` that is on the `UINavigationController` stack, not with a new one that I want to create.

Comment: @Flexicoder what would you suggest instead of a `UINavigationController` for this task?

Comment: Before pushing new controller, call pop on navigation with `NO` animation and immediately push the new one. This gives you what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The way I've controlled this before is to use `NSNotificationCenter` then post messages to something the appDelegate is listening too and get it to swap out the `rootViewController`

Comment: Question is why ? May help us to suggest alternatives/better ways to achieve what you want. This seem's a little 'hacky' ...

Comment: @CW0007007 [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391148/uinavigationcontroller-alternatives) you can read the motivation behind this approach. Basically I have lots of multimedia content in each `UIViewController` and I don't want to have memory issues stacking the `UINavigationController` with a lot of `UIViewControllers`

Comment: @Amar I'm trying what you suggest using this code: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:NO]` but it shows the root ViewController, not the one being pushed.

Comment: @guardabrazo Make sure you are calling `self.navigationController` from a VC already on the navigation stack. Otherwise the `navigationController` property is `nil`. I'd suggest you to add actual code in your question. It would be easier to figure out the issue.

Comment: @Amar I'll edit my question with actual code and a link to a zip file with a sample in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to make navigation controller to contain only one viewController.

```
-(IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender
{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[secondVC] animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code as you can see in the last edit of my question, but the memory still adds up every time I jump to a new `ViewController`