# UIViewController not being released from memory when popped

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` and I'm trying to release from memory every `UIViewController` once another one is on top of the stack. I assign the `viewControllers` property of the `UINavigationController` to the new `UIViewController` and then pop into it. This way I always have just one `UIViewController` in stack. However, the memory keeps adding up every time I create a new `UIViewController`. Dealloc is called, but the memory usage remains the same.

You can download the example project [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzc0ZnJg9-LZLU5ZODA4bGNnTzQ/edit?usp=sharing)

**FirstViewController.h**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)goToSecond:(id)sender;

@end
```

**FirstViewController.m**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);

}

-(void)goToSecond:(id)sender{

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[secondVC]];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

-(void)dealloc{

    NSLog(@"FirstVC dealloc");
}
@end
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)goToFirst:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController.viewControllers);

}

-(void)goToFirst:(id)sender{

    FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[firstVC]];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}

-(void)dealloc{

    NSLog(@"SecondVC dealloc");
}

@end
```

Comment: why would you do that? UINavigation bar keeps track of your memory and releases the right view on time, if you would like to have one view controller at all times, do not use navigation controller. or even don't use ark, so you can release it. But i would not advice you to do so.

Comment: If you want to go back then a simple `pushViewController` and `popViewController` should be preferred.

Comment: @PiratM, what would you suggest instead of the `UINavigationController`? I just need one `ViewController` at a time.

Comment: @YasKuraishi I've tried `push` and `pop` but the memory consumed by the `ViewController` remains the same. You can check it out in the example project. You can see how the memory graph rises when `SecondViewController` is created but then when it's popped the memory doesn't decrease.

Comment: @guardabrazo How many viewControllers do you have in your app? Do you need the "back" functionality on all of them? What is your memory usage that makes you need to release them? In case you have only few ViewContollers, you can build a fake navigation controller of your own. With just a simple view that looks exactly the same, but uses presentsView controller, and dismissViewController.

Comment: @PiratM I have over 20 viewControllers. Think of the app as a multimedia version of a 'Choose your own adventure' book. I load multiple images and videos so memory usage in each viewController can rise up to 100Mb or more. I don't need the 'back' functionality on all of them, just in some of them, but this 'back' doesn't have to be the previous viewController. [HERE](https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/vicente-hormiguero-gratis/id815649173?mt=8) is an example of an app that I guess has the functionality I'm looking for. I guess that once you complete a 'stage', it gets released from memory right?

Comment: I uploaded a project to GitUb with a fakeNavigation bar, take a look see if you find it helpful for your needs

Answer (score 0):

Navigation controller should not be used as you intended.
You should call `pushViewController` and `popViewController` for present/dismiss your viewControllers.
If you have memory issues, try to release memory in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` callback

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the benefit of a uinavigationcontroller but anyway you could add this snippet on your .m of your uiviewcontrollers

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];    
    if (self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        NSMutableArray *newViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
        [newViewControllers removeObject:[controllers objectAtIndex:1]];
        self.navigationController.viewControllers = newViewControllers;
    }
}
```

And instead of

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[firstVC]];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

you can set

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:[[FirstViewController alloc] init] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using pop to go further, but you need to use `push` if you want to go to the next `ViewController`.

```
-(void)goToSecond:(id)sender{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    [ self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}
```

And in the `SecondViewController` to go back to your `FirstViewController` you should use `pop`

```
-(void)backToController
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

In your case

```
-(void)goToFirst:(id)sender
 {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: I already know that normally I should use `push` to go further, but it will add the new `ViewController` to the stack of the 'UINavigationController` and I want to prevent that.

Comment: if you use `[self presentViewController:add animated:YES completion:nil];` and  then add a new `UINavigationController` to the `SecondViewController` ?

Comment: I can't try it at the moment. Could you elaborate the code a bit more? Maybe in a separate answer? I will test it as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded a simple app to GitHub, with the fake navigation bar that i was talking about in my comment, hope it helps for your needs: https://github.com/yosihashamen/HelpersApps

Be ware that you must keep on "BaseViewController" alive at all times.

Answer (score 0):

What I mean is something like this.

In your `FirstViewController` use `presentViewController` instead of `push` adding a new `UINavigationController` to the `SecondViewController`

```
-(void)goToSecond:(id)sender{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init]; 
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondVC];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NIL];

}
```

In the `SecondViewController` add an `UIBarButtonItem` to the `Navigation bar`

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:@selector(goToFirst:)];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

And implement dismiss method.

```
-(void)goToFirst:(id)sender
 {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out `setViewControllers:animated:`

This allows you to explicitly set the view controllers on the UINavigationController stack, like you are doing, and it will automatically handle the navigation animation without you having to call `popViewControllerAnimated:`

This is useful if you have a multi-view journey where you need to get rid of the screens that have been shown so far but maintain the navigation animation (eg. app demo on launch) or if you want to easily push multiple view controllers on the navigation stack at once.

Apple doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_21